# Smallest Lipschitz Constant of a Differentiable Function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be compact and convex. Moreover, let $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable map with $\sup_{x \in X} \|\nabla f(x)\| = K < \infty$, where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the Euclidean norm and $\nabla f$ the gradient.

Both [in this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115458/smallest-lipschitz-constant-on-non-convex-domains) and [in this webpage](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Lipschitz_constant) it is said that the best (minimal) Lipschitz constant of $f$ is $K$. If this is a basic result in real analysis, could someone please point me to a reference?

Comment: Undoubtedly this is in *Geometric Measure Theory* by Federer. But I think this question belongs on math.stackexchange.

Comment: It may be hard to find the proof in a textbook, but you can prove it yourself by taking a point $x$ with $\|\nabla f(x) \|\geq K-\varepsilon$ and finding a $y$ with $|f(y)-f(x)| \geq (K-2\varepsilon)|y-x|$ using the definition of differentiability at $x$.

Comment: @StanleySnelson: you have to check the reverse inequality too, which is where convexity comes in: any two points are joined by a line segment and you can apply the one-dimensional mean value theorem.

Comment: You know what, come to think of it, there's a proof of this in a book I just wrote ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially Corollary 1.42 in my book *Lipschitz Algebras* (second edition).